# How to call function with struct parameter in ethers?

Tags: ethers.js, struct, data-types, encoding, encodefunctioncall

My solidity:

```js
contract Test {

    struct Num {
        uint value;
    }

    function double(Num calldata num) external pure returns(Num memory) {
        return Num({ value: num.value * 2 });
    }
}
```

My ethers:

```js
await test.double(2); // doesn't work
await test.double([ 2 ]); // doesn't work
await test.double({ value: 2 }); // doesn't work
await test.double(ethers.BigNumber.from(2)); // doesn't work
await test.double([ ethers.BigNumber.from(2) ]); // doesn't work
await test.double({ value: ethers.BigNumber.from(2) }); // doesn't work
```

If I call a function that returns a `Num` type (with a value of 5 for example), I get:

```js
[
  BigNumber { value: "5" },
  value: BigNumber { value: "5" }
]
```

So I also tried:

```js
const params = [ ethers.BigNumber.from("2"), value: ethers.BigNumber.from("2") ]
await test.double(params);
```

But this doesn't even compile...

I also looked here: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/abi/coder/#AbiCoder-decode

[image]

This seems to return the type of structure I need. So I also tried:

```js
let params = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(
    [ 'uint value' ],
    [ 2 ]
);
params = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.decode([ "uint value" ], params);
await test.double(params) // doesn't work
```

But this doesn't work either...

Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For struct, you use an object to insert argument:

```
const data = {
    value: 100,
}
const tx = await test.double(data);
console.log(tx);
```

I tried and got the output:

```
[ 
BigNumber { value: "200" }, 
value: BigNumber { value: "200" } 
]
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get ```Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="double((uint256))", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.6.0)```

Comment: Actually, forget my last comment. That error was related to something else. Yes, your answer does work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to pass an argument to a struct, just try with square brackets, like so:

```
await contractName.functionFoo([exampleNumber]);
```

If a function returns a struct and you would like to interact with a key within it, you could also try:

```
let response = await contractName.functionFoo([exampleNumber])
// the number from the struct is now stored at response[0]
```

I recently wrote a contract that utilised structs and this is a snippet from my test file.

I hope I helped you, buddy! Keep hacking! :)